# Laravel PHPUnit failed to load file on first try, but worked on second try

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, php-8.1

I'm working on Laravel 9 running on PHP 8.1, doing some Unit Testing to load files under the `tests` directory

It's always failed on the first try since the code test is created. But it will work normally on the second try.

[image]

Is this have something to do with the `phpunit.xml` configuration?

Comment: Will you share the test code snippet and  the error logs?

Comment: What actually are you testing? We can't help you unless you give us more details.

Comment: The gif is super small when I open it, I can't understand anything

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, but if i run

> php artisan test

it works fine, I think there should be an issue with php unit installed globally.

Comment: yup same with me, if I run on command it works just fine